# Set app.config within a controller

Tags: angularjs

So, I have my `app.controller` and inside of it I have a request. When request is successful, I want to set retrieved data to some `$provider` property, i.e.

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function(){
  app.config(function($someProvider){
    $someProvider.property = response.data;
    $someProvider.function(response.data.status);
  })
})
```

I'm trying to set this within controller, but it does nothing. Any tips, guys? :)

Comment: As I've said in my answer, this question can be *refactored* to *Bootstrap AngularJS once async data is ready*. It's up to you if you'd like to change its title. At the moment, it's very specific and very unlikely to help others since they won't search this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question comes down to **how can I postpone angular's bootstrap process until I have some async data**.

For the async part, you can use (or do) whatever you want, it doesn't really matter. 
**Fun fact:** You can even use `$http` before bootstrapping angular just by getting it via `angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");`.

This being said, when you have all your async data, all that's left to do is to bootstrap angular. This can be achieved via `angular.bootstrap` - [source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization).

**Here's a working example** in which I asynchronously attach a controller (remember, you can do whatever you want: attach various constants, config blocks, etc). I've used `setTimeout` for simplicity's sake.

```js
// Initial Angular Code
angular.module('myApp', []);

// Async function. I've used setTimeout for simplicity's sake
setTimeout(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'Angular has started!';
      }
    ]);

  // Boostrap AngularJS
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('boostrap-me'), ['myApp']);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="boostrap-me" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-bind="value">Angular hasn't yet bootstrapped as we're waiting for some async data!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting stuff. Didn't even know about this.

Comment: Although, you can't bootstrap only some piece, i.e. one config section? You have to init all the app at once, right?

Comment: Technically, you can do this by bootstrapping multiple Angular applications. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

if default injecting doesn't do the job
maybe store your provider at config time to some other variable and use this var in controller later

but [angular says](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> During application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all services, it configures and instantiates all providers. We call this
>   the configuration phase of the application life-cycle. During this
>   phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created
>   yet.
>
> Once the configuration phase is over, interaction with providers is
>   disallowed and the process of creating services starts. We call this
>   part of the application life-cycle the run phase.

so i don't know if this will work

Comment: Thanks for clarification, now I know that it's impossible :)

Answer (score 2):

Newly added `config` blocks aren't executed after the ending of config phase, the same applies to other `app` methods because they result in additional `config` blocks internally.

It is possible with:

```
app.config(($provide, $someProvider) => {
  $provide.value('$someProvider', $someProvider);
});

app.controller('someCtrl', ($someProvider) => {
  $someProvider...
});
```

This voids the warranty and may indicate XY problem that should be solved the other way, depending on what `$someProvider` is and how it functions.

If `$some` is injected and used before setting `$someProvider`, this will result in race condition. If `$some` was changed at some point to not watch for `$someProvider` properties after instantiation, this will result in breaking changes without notice that will make the tests fail.

It is acceptable for badly designed third-party services that don't cause ill effects when being treated like that. And as any other hack, it should be thoroughly covered with tests.